# How can I keep Chrome Dev Tools from opening bundle.js in the Sources tab?

Tags: google-chrome, web-development, developer-tools

It sometimes takes me minutes to get to the console tab, because Chrome is busy loading bundle.js.

I would not care if the Sources tab would be gone altogether. I do use source maps and the debugger in combination with VS Code.